# Mouse cursor restarts after reboot

Tags: cursor, cursor-theme

I changed my mouse theme by several ways (like Unity Tweaks, the index file and dconf editor) but everytime I reboot my computer I need to run the "restart" command for the cursor theme to display correctly, any fix?